# XMLhttpRequest in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I try to create a custom form for hubspot. My HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="newsletterForm">
     <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Voornaam">
     <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail adres">
     <input type="submit" value="Houd mij op de hoogte!">
     <input type="checkbox" id="privacy" name="privacy" value="false">
     <label for="privacy">Ja, Ik ga akkoord met privacy voorwaarden.*</label><br>
</form>
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener( "load", function () {

  const form = document.getElementById( "newsletterForm" );

  form.addEventListener( "submit", function ( event ) {

          const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
      alert( event.target.responseText );
    } );

    // Define what happens in case of error
    XHR.addEventListener( "error", function( event ) {
      alert( 'Oops! Something went wrong.' );
    } );

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open( "POST", "https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/:portalId/:formGuid" );
    XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    XHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send({
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "email",
      "value": "ingejoppe@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "firstname",
      "value": "INge TEST"
    }
  ],
  "legalConsentOptions": {
    "consent": {
      "consentToProcess": true,
      "text": "I agree to allow Example Company to store and process my personal data.",
      "communications": [
        {
          "value": true,
          "subscriptionTypeId": 999,
          "text": "I agree to receive marketing communications from Example Company."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
    
  } );
} );

  </script>
```

When I click submit, I neatly end up in the correct function, only then XMLhttpRequest is not executed. The page is reloaded but the data is not sent. Is There Anything I'm Missing? I tried to send the object as JSON.stringify () with the XHR.Send () but that doesn't help either.

In the POST url I use the correct values. I can successfully perform the action via a direct POST request with the same content.

in short, am I overlooking something? Or do I need an AJAX library to use in plain-javascript for an XMLhttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

> The page is reloaded

That's what submitting a form does. And that navigation cancels the JS.

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the submit event.

`event.preventDefault()`

---

Aside: If you want to POST JSON then the value you pass to `send()` needs to be JSON and not an object.